# In welchem Sprachraum sind die Worte "Möhle", "möhlen" und "möhlig" verbreitet?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, vocabulary, dialect, regional

Ich habe soeben völlig erstaunt festgestellt, dass eine bestimmte Wortgruppe, die meine Familie und ich seit jeher benutzen, in keinem Wörterbuch zu finden ist. Da wir aus dem norddeutschen Raum kommen (Mecklenburg-Vorpommern / Brandenburg), dachte ich erst, es handelte sich hierbei vielleicht nur um Wörter aus einem Dialekt (meine Großeltern sprachen Platt). Aber selbst Google findet dazu nichts – was mich wirklich verblüfft!

Wo sind *die Möhle*, *möhlen* und *möhlig* verbreitet, und was ist ihre sprachliche Herkunft?

---

Bedeutungen nach meiner Auffassung: <sup>(Zum Anzeigen bitte mit der Maus über das gelbe Feld fahren!)</sup>

> **die Möhle**: die Unordnung, die Gesamtheit wahllos daliegender Gegenstände
>  **möhlen**: Unordnung schaffen, zwischen Gegenständen wahllos herumkramen
>  **möhlig**: unordentlich, verwüstet, mit wahllos herumliegenden Gegenständen übersäht

Comment: Bei uns (alemannischer Sprachraum) sagen wir [*nülen, nuelen, nuele*](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id4.htm#!page/40715/mode/1up) in ähnlicher Bedeutung. Sie auch [bei Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN06526#XGN06526).

Comment: Mir sind alle drei Wörter völlig unbekannt. Auch die von Takkat genannten Wörter habe ich noch nie gehört oder gelesen. Ich kenne aber auch keine anderen Wörter, die diese Bedeutungen haben.

Comment: Hier www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/6310-moehlig findet man was. Es handelt sich also um ein umganssprachliches Wort, welches für Ostdeutschland typisch ist. Interessanterweise taucht bei Google "Wirrwarr" auf wenn man "Möhle bedeutung" eingibt.

Comment: Ich kenne es als Unordentlich. Wenn zB eine Wohnung sehr unordentlich ist, dann ist es dort möhlig. Und sich zumöhlen bedeutet dann, dass man sehr unordentlich ist und Unordnung produziert.

Comment: Ich kenne das, möhlich -> unaufgeräumt, ein weggemöhlt -> nicht alle Tassen im Schrank, Möhlstahl -> Zimmer nicht aufgeräumt usw.

Comment: Ich komme aus Wismar und natürlich ist möhlig mir ein Begriff :) Mein Freund kommt aus Bayern und hatte vor mir auch noch nie davon gehört. Komisch die Südländer :P

Comment: „Möhlig“ ist in anderen Regionen anscheinend genauso wenig bekannt wie „dallern“. Wie oft haben früher unsere Lehrer geschimpft: „Hört auf rumzudallern und macht eure Möhle weg.“ Kaum zu glauben, dass beide Wörter nicht im Duden stehen.

Comment: In Schwerin ist das Wort möhlig / Möhle auch absoluter Standard. Umso mehr war auch ich gerade verwundert und erschrocken, dass es (immer noch nicht!) im Duden steht..

Comment: Ja als Mecklenburger ist es ein Standardbegriff, u.a. für Unordnung, Möhlecke wie beschreiben. Die Nichtmecklenburger können dazu lernen. Es bleibt zu hoffen, dass es bei ihnen nicht allzu möhlig ist.

Comment: Ich habe viele Jahre in Rostock gewohnt und kenne es zum einen als Möhle = Unordnung. Viele benutzen es aber auch so: "Hör auf zu möhlen und komm." Was soviel heißt wie: "Komm aus der Knete." oder "Beeil Dich.".

Comment: Ich komme aus Kühlungsborn (Mecklenburg-Vorpommern) und verwende ebenfalls die Worte "möhlig" und "Möhle". Stimmt, im Duden scheint es nicht zu stehen, ist mir jetzt auch aufgefallen.:) Jeder versteht hier aber, was damit gemeint ist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gemäss dem Wörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartssprache handelt es sich um ein umgangssprachliches mecklenburgisches Wort mit der Bedeutung ‘kramen, wühlen, herumsuchen’, vgl. [„mölen“, Wörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartssprache (1964–1977), kuratiert und bereitgestellt durch das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/m%C3%B6len).

Answer (score 9):

möhlen oder auch wöhlen kommt aus dem Plattdeutschen und bedeutet so viel wie wühlen, steht hier:
[http://plattmakers.de/de/17407/möhlen](http://plattmakers.de/de/17407/m%C3%B6hlen)

> möhlen (/mœɪ̯ln̩/, Verb, Plattdeutsch)
>   [1]Karte
>   Bedeutung:
>
> Plattdeutsch:
>   wöhlen
>   Deutsch:
>   wühlen
>
> Etymologie:
>
> von Möhl:
>
> > Möhl (/ˈmœɪ̯l/, Substantiv, Plattdeutsch)
> >     Möhlen, f
> >
> > Plattdeutsch:
> >     Mahlanlaag för Koorn
> >     Niederländisch:
> >     meulen gem
> >     Englisch:
> >     mill gem
> >     Deutsch:
> >     Mühle gem

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich In Deiner Frage stand aber auch, dass Du keine Informationen finden konntest, ob es sich um Wörter aus einem Dialekt handeln. Und Tina hat den Dialekt bestätigt und einen Wörterbucheintrag geliefert :)

Comment: Wenn das von Mühle hergeleitet wird, wie kommt denn dann die Unordnung darein?

Answer (score 3):

Ich komm aus Stuttgart und auch mir ist das Wort möhlig bekannt, woher ich es kenne weiß ich nicht aber ich kenne das Wort auch mit der Bedeutung unordentlich, so wie dus übersetzt hast. Ich benutze es vor allem, wenn Zeug auf dem Boden liegt.

Answer (score 3):

In Prenzlau (Nordosten Brandenburgs) ist das Wort absolut im Sprachgebrauch. Es bedeutet in der Regel unordentlich.

Es wird wie folgt häufig angewendet:

- möhlig (Adjektiv) = es ist unaufgeräumt, unordentlich.
- herummöhlen (Verb) = etwas ohne große Energie durchwühlen und damit unordentlich machen.
- die Möhlecke (Substantiv) = ein unordentlicher Bereich im Zimmer oder in einem Schrank.
- die Möhlbude (Substantiv) = ein unordentliches Zimmer.